# Reveal location of a selected file in Finder (macOS) from "Project" pane of IntelliJ

Tags: file, intellij-idea, filesystems, finder

In IntelliJ 2020.3.1, I want to select a Java source code value in the *Project* pane, and then show that file in the [macOS Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) file-system viewer.

Many apps include a `Reveal in Finder…` menu item in the context menu. But I cannot find such an item in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020.3.1, it is now called "Open in Finder".

```
Right click on file > Open In > Finder
```

[image]